# 2 Crossovers in parallel: how are frequencies distributed?

Tags: audio, passive-filter, frequency-response

So, the other day I connected on parallel a dual-voice subwoofer-system (a Pyle XSUB1-150-4-12d crossover —  [like this one](https://m.ebay.com/itm/1-NOS-PYLE-XSUB1-Subwoofer-Crossover-300-WATTS-/312405063599) ... link might be unavailable after Aug 28, 2019 ... — and 2 individual subwoofers) with a 3-way-speaker-system (Weconic) and they sound good together! As far as I can hear with the help of a 7-band-equalizer (100Hz, 200Hz, 400Hz, 800Hz, 1.6kHz, 3.2kHz, 6.4kHz) there is no frequency not being reproduced and the 3-way-speaker seems to receive less of the waves with frequencies below — and arround — 100Hz than the "dual-voice-subwoofer". This is the "roll off point" of the XSUB1 crossover.

I wonder how the distribution happens... and have some doubts...
++ **UPDATED** ++ (based on the first 4 comments)

1. Does the XSUB1 crossover "pull" the frequencies below-and-around 100Hz? Or does it "block" the others >100Hz?
2. Or does the XSUB crossover-elememts absorb the frequencies I don't hear through the subwoofers? Are these transformed to heat or magnetic fields in the capacitor or coil? respectively?
3. Should I know more about what a crossover's "roll off point" does to the frequencies?

Sorry if my questions are pointing in different or vague directions and thanks for helping me know what happens to the information travelling!

++ **EDIT** ++

Here are the wiring instructions of the XSUB1:
[image]
I've been unable to find any information on the XSAT3-150-12d.

Here is a handmade schematic of the complete system:
[image: handmade schematic of the complete system]
with some of the data/measurements.

I have used components from several items:

- two identical subwoofers
- 100Hz stereo crossover
- Yamaha NS-G7's 3-way-crossover
- Weconic 3-way-drivers.

It turns out the tweeter of these drivers is dead... so I can't give an Ohm value...

Comment: Does the "XSUB1" have a data sheet that explains what it does? If so, then link it. If not then what are you hoping anyone answering will have technically to hand that could answer your questions?

Comment: Schematic? Block diagram?

Comment: thanx for the comments! the link I posted has 5 pictures with a little bit of information but incomplete... The XSUB is a simple L-C crossover. One coil, one capacitor. I will post the capacitor's capacitance once I am back home. Unfortunately, I have not found any information on the inductance...

Comment: Any details on the 3-way? Do they reproduce the low frequencies when the sub is not connected? The roll-off may be a natural consequence of their size. Detecting where sub-100Hz frequencies come from is not easy, the wavelength is long enough that the ear cannot determine the direction of the source - which is why you can get away with a single sub in a stereo or multi-channel system.

Comment: Thanx @PhilG. I had to touch the 3-way to be sure. It turns out they DO reproduce sub-100Hz also :/ ... editing post now ...

Comment: check this incomplete introduction:      https://physics.info/circuits-rlc/

Comment: also check: https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Tables/ButterworthCrossover/2ndOrder/ for the 100Hz-LC-Subwoofer-Filter

Comment: ... and this: https://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Tables/ButterworthCrossover/1stOrder/ for the C-Tweeter-Filter (I believe it is at 9kHz)